# react init app only after calling function in html file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently building app in React.js that is suppose to be a advanced widget. Main requirement is that app should initialise only when at some point in time someone will execute function:

```
startApp({
    someData: 'test',
    wrap: 'domSelector'
});
```

i found this article [Link](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-data-hydration-initialization-bacbb790c7cb), where author claims you can do this:

```
<div id="MyApp"></div>
<script>
    window.runReactApplication({
         user: { name: 'BTM', email: 'example@example.com' }
    }, document.querySelector('#MyApp'));
</script>
```

and index.js

```
function runApplication(data, node) {
    ReactDOM.render(<App data={data} />, node);
}
window.runReactApplication = runApplication;
```

It doesnt work for me as i get `runReactApplication` is undefined error.
Just out of curiosity i tried to wrap execution around `timeout` and it worked:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.runReactApplication({
            user: { name: 'BTM', email: 'example@example.com' }
        }, document.querySelector('#MyApp'));
    }, 150);
</script>
```

i can guess that in production its not a big problem because i can include app code first and then script so i have guarantee that function is added to the window.

But in development environment its a problem i dont know how to solve, and having timeout around function is obviously crazy. Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Use `global.runReactApplication = …`?

Comment: i tried that if i say `global.runReactApplication =` and then in `index.html` i do `runReactApplication()` or `global.runReactApplication()` it says it is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic imports instead of setTimeout.

Let's say all of your react logic is bundled inside of `index.js`. Simply do the following to ensure that `index.js` has been downloaded and run before the desired DOM attachment:

```js
import('index.js').then(() => {
   window.runReactApplication({
         user: { name: 'BTM', email: 'example@example.com' }
   }, document.querySelector('#MyApp'));
}
```

If you want to preload the `index.js` file for optimal speed, simply add

```html
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

to the head of your `index.html` file.

---

In the broader context, however, I am not sure why your `startApp` function wouldn't simply be:

```js
function startApp(params){
    const {data, selector} = params;
    ReactDOM.render({
         <App data={data} />
    }, document.querySelector(selector));
}
```

And you could just bind this as a callback to whatever html event you want (i.e., `onClick` for a button, `onLoad` for the document loading, etc.).

```js
 button.onclick = startApp({data:{email: me@test.com}, selector: 'domSelector'});
```